# Heroku task stage not found

Tags: kotlin, heroku, ktor

I'm trying to deploy my project onto Heroku, I followed [this tutorial](http://sebi.io/general/2018/08/15/Kotlin-on-Heroku.html) and [this one](https://medium.com/@dariopellegrini/deploy-a-kotlin-server-in-minutes-using-ktor-and-heroku-ed6ed33337f) but none worked for me.

My gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

version '0.0.1'
mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.jetty.EngineMain"

task stage(dependsOn: ['clean', 'installDist'])

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

    //Log
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"

    //KTor core
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-jetty:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
...
```

I've created the `Procfile` with `web: ./build/install/my-ws/bin/my-ws`

I've run `./gradlew stage` in my terminal and it worked fine.

But when I do `git push heroku master` I still get the error

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Gradle app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Building Gradle app...
remote: -----> executing ./gradlew stage
remote:        Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip
remote:        ...............................................................................................................
remote:        
remote:        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
remote:        
remote:        * What went wrong:
remote:        Task 'stage' not found in root project 'my-ws'.
remote:
```

Comment: if you wants to deploy ktor app on heroku .. please read this medium blog on ktor app deployment https://nameisjayant.medium.com/deploy-ktor-app-with-postgresql-on-heroku-ff35df4b5c55

Answer (score 1):

Simply goto build.gradle file and paste the below code.

```
tasks.create("stage") {
    dependsOn("installDist")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your stage task resides in the **root project**. If not, declare one with a dependency on a subproject's task:

```
task stage(dependsOn: [':subproject:stage'])
```

Comment: same result, I've tried what you said and `task stage(dependsOn: [':subproject:stage','installDist'])`